# Why don't you connect unused hot and neutral wires to "complete the circuit"?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm new to home wiring and had a question I'd like explained to me. I removed a vent hood over my oven and I thought I had to complete the circuit so I tied the hot and neutral wires that were powering the hood together with a wire nut, but all the lights on that breaker in the house didn't work after that. I then tried turning on the breaker with the hot and neutral wires NOT touching and all the lights worked!

This doesn't make sense to me; this might be a super simple question but I'm just trying to understand.

Why did the breaker work when those two wires weren't connected, but when I secured them with a wire nut then all of the lights also on that breaker didn't work?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. If you're describing this accurately, you're lucky not to have caused a fire or electrocuted yourself. You might want to get a professional involved.

Comment: If you have to ask this question, you should leave wiring to the professionals. Answering this is way beyond the scope of this forum.

Comment: @Skoant, don't get mad at comments that tell it like it is. Daniel & Bill were just making very valid points. You are messing with something that can be very dangerous that you obviously have absolutely no clue about. Coming here and asking why a dead short tripped a breaker proves this. Maybe get some background and knowledge first and *then* attempt this sort of project?

Comment: Normally there's something in-between the two wires that limits the flow of electricity. If you connect them directly to each other then too much electricity can flow, which has a tendency to make wires get really hot and catch fire, which is why circuit breakers exist. (The electricity also won't do anything useful)

Comment: Not "smarter" but ethical and careful. It's dangerous to give anonymous advice (or even just information) when home electrical wiring is being discussed. No one wants responsibility for what can happen, so there is extra caution. It's also hard to put helpful tones of into text, so it can be misinterpreted.

Comment: The only possible advice is "read an basic electricity textbook". Unfortunately I don't know any that's why I can't post it as answer.

Comment: It is good that you are trying to understand how that works, but please leave any further electrical-related work to professionals, for your sake and that of everyone around you. You clearly have very little notions of how electricity works, and it is a dangerous thing to mess with.

Comment: I'd like to try to reiterate what others are saying, as politely as I can, in hopes that helps cement the message.  There are hundreds of ways you can set fire to your house, kill yourself, or even kill other innocent people by making mistakes with wiring.  The electrical community at large has an opinion about how much you should know before undertaking a home wiring task, and what order you should learn things in.  The question you ask is typically considered something you need to know *long* before touching an actual circuit, and shows that you do not have any of the accepted models...

Comment: ... of how electricity works in your head.  This has scared people, and that is why they are so snippy.  There is a fear that, if they give you the information you want, that you may actually try to do more electrical work, rather than seeking professional help.  They don't want to feel responsible for any damage that may occur because of it.  You got lucky this time. You are alive, and your house didn't catch fire. Based on what you have said, it's hard for us to consider it anything but luck, because we can't tell if you know any basic safety or not. Knowledge is power -- power is dangerous.

Comment: If you had admitted to this as a resident of anywhere in the European Union, you could be prosecuted (as well as electrocuted). It is such a serious issue, which has in the past cost lives, that any work on a mains electrical circuit must be carried out by a certificated, qualified professional. It surprises me that the law is not the same in the US, where I am guessing you are.
Don't risk it - pay someone who knows what they are doing, and has the documentation to prove it. (And the Liability Insurance!) It could save your house!

Comment: Please do not do  your own home wiring.  In most countries, there are laws about what qualifications you need to have, in order to do this kind of thing.  Those laws save lives.  You could kill somebody.  You could burn down your house.  Please never do this again.

Comment: The thinking in the US (The Land of the Free to Do Yourself In) is that homeowners, being the individuals at risk, will take the necessary precautions out of a sense of self-preservation when working on their own homes. For everyone else's home, it takes a licenced pro.

Comment: The notion that only a for hire electrician can do electrical work on their own home is false. You can get away with doing some electrical jobs around the home by yourself, as long as you have adequate training, follow local codes, and take proper safety precautions. That being said, if you lack the basic skills, and common sense when dealing with electric, then you should hire a professional. It is permissible to create a dead short in a circuit by connecting the hot and neutral leads together when you abandon a circuit. This will trip the breaker and prevent you from having loose live wires

Comment: @user61029 there are many places in the US where this is actually the law... Technically in the town where I live a permit needs to be pulled for any electrical (or plumbing) work, and they will only issue those permits to electricians (or plumbers). And to be in compliance with the law once the work is done you have to have the work inspected afterward. I've never heard of someone being prosecuted, but when selling the home you have to attest that no work had been completed on the home without a permit being pulled for it.

Comment: @user61029: One big difference is that North American mains power is only 110 V. Although that doesn't make it safe, it means it's not quite as deadly. Where I live, sure, go ahead and do your own wiring (you're supposed to get a permit for anything more than minor work, but they'll issue those to anyone). But your own plumbing? Goodness, no! You might get wet!

Comment: @BillOertell SE sites are not forums :)

Comment: Your story here reminds me of another similar circumstance. In college, I took an art class where we had to make a lamp. The instructor gave us wires with plugs and the light socket. One girl came back with an exploded bulb and threw up her hands at what went wrong. She had taken the wires, stripped them a good 4", threaded them meticulously through the holes in the bottom, mashed it all down into a wad at the bottom, and screwed the bulb in on top. I bet the resulting shower of sparks was a spectacle to behold. I'm still amazed she didn't get a nasty shock from that.

Comment: Guys, software engineer here, I have some basics in EE but only so much. I've connected a few lamps and sockets, but I'm not able to rate my ability. This forum is where I often look for advice. Where do I *"get some background and knowledge first"*? How do I know the point where I'm entitled to ask questions here rather than hiring a professional? Please try to be as actionable as possible when giving feedback like this.

Comment: @cat, the term "forum" was meant loosely (obviously!), and I'm not sure what my use of the word, as opposed to some other, perhaps, more appropriate synonym, has to do with the subject matter at hand.

Comment: Another point that hasn't been raised - Motors shouldn't be on lighting circuits.  The range hood will have an extractor fan as well as lights.  Locations may vary but here lighting circuits are lower capacity, and not rated for higher loads.  Bathroom vent fans retrofitted cause the same issues when the fitting reuses the lighting circuit wiring.

Comment: @Kos I know it's over three years late... but you get said experience by doing lots of reading of *actual, authoritative educational material* (read: not the internet, possibly barring sites whose explicit purpose is to provide an educational foundation). I have a 35 year old book by the venerable Forrest M. Mims III, "Getting Started in Electronics", that taught me basic electrical principles and precautions when I was about 7 years old. One book, 128 wide-margin, large-print pages with plenty of illustrations... and I'd already gathered that I shouldn't connect random wires willy-nilly.

Comment: @DoktorJ I appreciate your answer! Since 2016 I had a chance to learn a little and do a few Arduino projects. The rabbit hole goes deep: The more I learn the less I feel I know...

Comment: @Kos it's kinda fascinating and just makes you want to learn more though, doesn't it? :D

Answer (score 106):

You don't need to "complete the circuit".  Tying together the hot and neutral wires creates a short circuit, which should immediately trip the circuit breaker.  If you're removing a vent hood, you should put a wire nut on the end of each now-unused wire (to prevent a short circuit) and close up the box.

Every unused outlet in the house is an "incomplete circuit".  Presumably you don't install jumper wires across each outlet every time you unplug something, right?

Comment: Just because of the nature of the question, I think we need to specify that you put wire nuts on all the unused wires _individually_ so they don't touch each other or anything else.

Comment: It's perhaps worth pointing out that the "incomplete circuit" that was opened by removing the appliance was also *opened every time the appliance was turned off.*

Answer (score 83):

Here is what happened.  Before you started, this is what the system looked like:

[image]

Then you removed the vent hood:

[image]

OK so far.  But then *"I thought I had to complete the circuit so I tied the hot and neuteral wires that were powering the hood together with a wire nut"*.  I can't even begin to guess how you dreamed up the idea of tying the hot and neutral lines together, but here is a diagram of it:

[image]

Bzzzt.  Poof.  Note that there is now a complete circuit from hot, thru the breaker, back to neutral.  Or more accuractly, a *short circuit*.  Fortunately the breaker is meant to open the circuit when exactly this kind of failure occurs.  It kept the wires from getting very hot and burning your house down.  No, seriously.

Since the breaker tripped, it shut off power in that circuit.  That is why the lights that are on the same breaker don't work anymore.

This also demonstrates why the laws require a licensed electrician to do work on power wiring.  Amateurs *that know what they're doing* can make useful changes, but these changes are not legal (in most modern countries), and almost certainly violate your insurance policy.  If your house had burned down due to this, the insurance company would have legitimate reason not to pay.

Unfortunately, as you have shown, those that don't know what they're doing also don't know that they don't know.  The laws have to be universal, so require certain training and certification for doing things that could cause serious injury and property loss.

Basically, **stop monkeying with stuff you don't understand**.  You are very lucky that you didn't manage to defeat the remaining safety system (the circuit breaker), and it saved you from your own stupidity.  Next time you may not be so lucky.  Ordinary circuit breakers don't save you from electrocution, for example.

Comment: In your last paragraph you should say "ignorance" instead of "stupidity". If OP was really stupid he would have kept trying to make his concepts work instead of asking for help. - He would not be posting here; he would be over on Law SE trying to find out why his home insurance provider won't pay out for his burned down house.

Comment: Hi Olin, good explanation. In every state that I've lived in (west coast USA: CA, OR, WA, NV) homeowners can do electrical work on their own residence without any training or licensing. But they do need to get a permit before they do the work, and have it inspected by a professional.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri It's only ignorance if he didn't know that there are rules limiting this type of electrical work to those with appropriate qualifications and that electrical problems are a major cause of fires in modern homes. It's stupidity if he did and didn't bother to find out what was and was not safe for him to do.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri The **ignorance** of electricity caused the immediate problem. The **stupidity** is not thinking "electricity is dangerous, maybe I should solve my ignorance before messing with it".  It is true that the OP might be ignorant of how dangerous electricity is, but that would require a profound amount of ignorance.  The OP made an error that was one other independant error away from burning down the house and/or killing someone.  The very final "save you from disaster" fail-safe kicked in before the OP realized they screwed up.  That is *not good*.

Comment: No one's mentioned that the closed-circuit isn't a short-circuit because when you close a circuit to a light, or a vent hood fan, those have resistance. The circuit breaker is designed to let a measured (through a load/resistance) amount of amps through, but when there is no load (when you connect hot to neutral) too many amps go through and the breaker breaks the connection.

Comment: I upvoted you until you used the word stupid. Then a downvote instead. @arluin has a good point above. We close circuits all the time so it seems natural that closing the loop how op did it would make sense. Except he didn't provide any resistance. That was his misunderstanding.

Comment: As @bitsmack pointed out, the laws do NOT "require a licensed electrician to do work on power wiring". They do, however, require permits and inspections; also, even if you do get the permit but your wiring burns the house down, your insurance won't cover that. If a licensed electrician does the work and THEIR wiring burns the house down, their contractor's insurance WILL pay for the damage (that's what they have it for, in addition to other things like on-the-job injuries etc).

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Ignorance = not being aware of how something works. Stupidity = not acknowledging a reasonable amount of ignorance and diving right in instead of preparing. Smart folks say "I have no idea how this works, I'm going to do some research before I try it". Stupid = doing the research *after* you nearly electrocute yourself / burn your house down. The OP presumably *did* continue to try their concepts before asking for help, based on the question how many times do you think they blindly attempted to flip that breaker back on before giving up?

Comment: @JoePhilllips `We close circuits all the time so it seems natural that closing the loop how op did it would make sense.` Well, no. It's like the answer above said: When you unplug something from an outlet, do you shove a metal bar into it to close the circuit? No, you just leave the circuit open. Removing a hood would be just the same. What OP did instead is equivalent to saying 'OK, there's no hood here anymore to use a _measured_ amount of current _sometimes_ when switched on, so I'd better fix up the circuit to **always use absolutely all the current**'. How is that not ludicrous reasoning?

Comment: @underscore_d The op wasn't unplugging something from an outlet, he was doing the equivalent of removing an outlet. In a house, you will often feed one outlet box from another or even from one outlet to another (see: gfi outlets). If you apply that knowledge to what the OP did you can kind of understand his confusion, being new to the concepts. He made the mistake of misunderstanding which wires to tie together (or to not tie together in his case)

Comment: Those are nice images, but they literally just restate the question -- "you had it this way and then you put it this way, but it's not supposed to be that way, you idiot" -- without at any point explaining why. Thankfully there are much better answers below that *actually address* the question, instead of just saying, basically, "it doesn't go that way, stupid." This should not be anywhere near the top answer.

Answer (score 50):

You seem to be under the impression your electrics work like this:
[image]

When infact, your circuit will more than likely look something like this
[image]

To bridge the live and neutral causes a short back to the distribution board, which can quite easily cause fires. Please, do not do this kind of work if you do not understand the basics of how it works. I am not trying to be condescending here, but people die doing stuff like this; If you are not 100% sure, consult with a professional.

Comment: Good point that hasn't been clearly mentioned yet. in your first diagram, the appliances are in _series_ while in the second they are in _parallel_. You could improve the diagrams somewhat by showing which of the little boxes represents the breaker/power supply and which are the appliances/outlets.

Comment: @Carl agreed, I threw this post together before heading in to a meeting at work... I'll clean it up when i get chance.

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer, I don't know why I had to scroll down so far to find it.  House wiring is done in parallel, not series.

Comment: A slight nitpick. The bottom picture shows a so-called ring circuit, a type of circuit previously commonly used in the UK to share the load between two parallel circuits. Not only are those circuits uncommon in the rest of the world, but it also potentially distracts from the point for a complete beginner. "Does each wire now have to be connected in a ring to work?"

Comment: @nitro: A single circuit in a typical house looks like the diagram above. UK homes are unique in that they (typically) have *just* one circuit. In a typical house in the rest of the world, fuses/breakers are in one central location, one for each circuit. In a ring-circuit home, each appliance has its own fuse.

Comment: @FighterJet I Think nitro's major concern is that the UK uses 'ring mains' when the majority of rest of the world do not. The only reason we use it was following world war 2 it saved on copper as you can use thinner wire on a ring, but its inherently more dangerous if the ring gets broken. Alot of countries still use a centralised fuse board, but do not have a ring, and only one pair of thicker wires to the location power is to be delivered. Also, i would say its incorrect to say most uk homes have one circuit. Most uk homes at the very least seperate lights from sockets, if not by area.

Comment: @FighterJet LIke James suggested, my concern is that the answer might be confusing because the rest of the world typically isn't using a ring circuit, and because it may distract from the question about "completing a circuit". I do know how ring mains works so you don't need to explain that to me.

Comment: I don't know of any UK homes that have "Just one circuit".  Maybe in the 1930s, when my house was built with an electric socket upstairs AND one downstairs!  Plus the cooker point, of course. 
 
I have 3 consumer units (fuseboxes with breakers in) and at least 6 ring mains.  My house is not particularly unusual in this.

Answer (score 39):

Let's try the water analogy.

The hot wire (black) is the water supply, the neutral wire is the drain. Your vent hood is a dishwasher.

Normally a dishwasher is connected to both supply and drain, but it also has valves and a place to do some work.

You have removed the dishwasher, along with its valves, pumps, etc. and connected the water supply directly to the drain.

This would normally cause a pressure drop in your house (showers, taps etc. don't work) and a huge bill at the end of the month, except your supply has a device that detects excess flow from the supply-to-drain connection and shuts it off.

When you remove an electrical appliance like your vent, the proper process is putting a wire nut on EACH wire, not both wires. Just like we would cap the supply and drain pipes after pulling the dishwasher.

If there are several wires in the outlet box, we often join all the wires of the same color together, but before this is done each wire must be investigated to ensure that tying them together is appropriate and safe.

Comment: The shortcoming in this analogy is that if I connect a supply pipe directly to the drain, the pipes don't catch fire :)

Comment: @Hobbs, true, but if you have a well, it is likely to fail after a while.

Comment: "If there are several wires in the outlet box, we join all the wires of the same colour together." - This is unwise and possibly dangerous advise. You shouldn't arbitrarily connect wires together based on their color, without investigating the source of the wires first. I've seen junction boxes where all of the wires in the box had the same color. You simply don't know if the person who wired the box knew what they were doing or paid any attention to the color of the wires they used.

Comment: Note, however, that there's not a shutoff for excess water flow installed by default (the breaker analogy fails) - at least in any house I've lived in. Such devices are available, though.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the classic water analogy (it often falls short anyways); I think the only reason folks seem to be able to wrap their head around water more easily than electricity is the fact that everybody always describes everything in terms of the "water analogy" to begin with. It's electricity, not water!

Comment: I  don't know what country the OP lives in.  Where I come from, the neutral wire is always either black or blue.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - Sure. But anyone talking about "hot" wires rather than "live" wires, and talking about wire nuts, is almost certainly from the US, not Europe.

Answer (score 25):

There's some great answers here already, but I thought maybe showing some maths would help with understanding.

#### *NOTES*

- *To keep things a bit simpler, we're going to focus on purely resistive loads, and ignore impedance, power factor, etc.*
- *To get more accurate result, we'll include the resistance of all the wiring in the circuit. For all the examples, we'll assume 200' of 12 AWG copper wire is used (0.00193 ohms/ft). Unless otherwise specified*

We'll start with a simple circuit, that contains only a single 60 watt light bulb

[image: power supply connected to bulb with 240 ohms resistance]

We can calculate the total resistance like this

```
Rt = R1 + R2
```

Here `Rt` is the total resistance, `R1` is the resistance of the light bulb, while `R2` is the resistance of the wire.

```
Rt = 240 ohms + 0.386 ohms
Rt = 240.386 ohms
```

Next, we can use Ohm's law to calculate the total current through the circuit.

```
It = E / Rt  
It = 120 volts / 240.386 ohms  
It = 0.499 amperes
```

Through this example, you can see that the circuit will only draw about half an ampere.

What would happen if we removed the light bulb, and "completed the circuit"?

[image: power supply with one end of the same wire connected to each terminal]

With the light bulb gone, the only resistance in the circuit is the wire.

```
Rt = 0.386 ohms
```

Using that to calculate the current

```
It = 120 volts / 0.386 ohms  
It = 310.88 amperes
```

We end up with a current draw 15.5 times the rated current (20 amperes) allowed by the circuit breaker. This causes the circuit breaker to trip, and open the circuit.

Next we'll take a look at a more complex example, where we have three bulbs in parallel.

[image: circuit with 3 bulbs with 240 ohms resistance, each on its own branch]

To calculate the resistance in a parallel circuit, it's not as simple as adding the resistances together. Instead you have add the reciprocals, and divide 1 by the result.

```
Rt = 1 / (1/R1 + 1/R2 + 1/R3)
Rt = 1 / (1/240 ohms + 1/240 ohms + 1/240 ohms) 
Rt = 80 ohms
```

Next we'll have to add in the resistance of the wire in the circuit.

```
Rt = 80 ohms + 0.386 ohms
Rt = 80.386 ohms
```

We can calculate the current through the circuit:

```
It = 120 volt / 80.386 ohms  
It = 1.49 amperes
```

Finally, let's remove one of the bulbs and "complete the circuit".

[image: same circuit with one bulb removed and the space it filled closed, so one branch is just wire]

In this example, the bulb resistance will be replaced by the resistance of 1' of 12 AWG copper wire.

```
Rt = 1 / (1/240 ohms + 1/240 ohms + 1/0.00193 ohms  
Rt = 0.001929969 ohms
```

Again we have to add in the resistance of the wire in the circuit.

```
Rt = 0.001929969 ohms + 0.386 ohms 
Rt = 0.387929969 ohms
```

Due to the low resistance, we can assume the current will be quite high.

```
It = 120 volts / 0.387929969 ohms
It = 309.3341829759 amperes
```

Once again the current is more than 15.5 times the rated circuit capacity, which should hopefully trip the circuit breaker.

---

## tl;dr

By "completing the circuit", you're actually creating a short-circuit (low resistance path).  Because the resistance through this path is so low, the current will always be quite high.  The circuit breaker reacts to the high current, and opens the circuit before the wiring can be damaged.

Comment: +1 for showing some numbers, for both parallel and series circuits!

Comment: Great answer but WAY over the OP's head, so not so great in that regard.

Comment: @CareyGregory So? This might be exactly the kind of thing the OP wants to learn. Either way, with respect, who cares? SE exists to provide information for everyone, not just the OP.

Comment: I realized recently that the US are actually using the international system of units for electrical stuff.

Comment: @njzk2 What are the international units for voltage, current, and resistance?

Comment: @Tester101 Volt (V), Amperes (A), and Ohm (Ω) (ohm and volt are derived units, though). I just though that was suprising, given how a/ the US are reluctant to adopt the international system for distances, weights, and volumes, and b/ those electricity units are defined based on other international units, including meters and kg.

Comment: @MarkBooth If I moved the tl;dr; to the top, nobody would read the rest of the post ;)

Comment: Ah, I see, so only the people who read through your whole post get the benefit if the section designed for the people who can't be bothered to read the whole post. That makes sense... *8')

Comment: @CareyGregory I disagree. You don't have to fully understand the math here to have the realization, "*oh, right, the circuit is "completed" when something is plugged in, but there's something between the hot and neutral side that's providing resisitance, and even if I don't totally understand what that means, I'm starting to understand why that's different from connecting the wires directly.*" In that respect, this is a very good answer that can be understood on various different levels.

Answer (score 22):

The other answers are all helpful but I thought it might be good to add one that is limited to your direct question:

> Why did the breaker work when those two wires weren't connected, but
>   when I secures them with a wire nut then all of the lights also on
>   that breaker didn't work?

The breaker *did* work. A circuit breaker's job is to interrupt, or "break", the circuit and stop the flow of electricity in case of a fault. In this case, the fault was the short circuit created when you tied those two wires together. So the breaker did exactly what it was supposed to do.

Answer (score 14):

A *complete circuit* allows power to flow. You don't want power to flow unless it is doing something useful. If the two wires are connected with each other, with no load, such as a light or a toaster in between, the current will flow but it will only heat the wires briefly until the circuit breaker trips.

You can think of the hot lead (usually black or red) as *out* and the neutral lead (white) as *back* or *return*. When you put a load (a light, a vacuum, a range hood) between the hot and the neutral, power flows. This is parallel wiring. You can have multiple separate loads between the hot and the neutral. Each of them is connected to the hot side and the neutral side. When no device is working (drawing power), no current flows. There is never a direct connection between the hot and the neutral wires.

When you remove the load, with a switch that breaks the connection, or when you remove it entirely, power does not flow. As noted elsewhere, when you disconnect a load, you cap each unused wire separately so power does **not** flow, even accidentally.

The notions that you need to *complete the circuit* only applies in serial wiring, which home wiring is **not**.

Comment: *You don't want power to flow unless it is doing something.* - The power is doing something in a short circuit: It's heating the wires. Copper wiring has resistance like any other component.

Comment: Although you're not necessarily completing the *circuit*, you do need to connect wires together to feed other things in a circuit which is very similar to serial wiring

Comment: I like this answer because it doesn't use the term "short circuit".     Somebody with the knowledge level of the person who asked the question is unlikely to know what a short circuit is or why it would be problematic. This answer explains the fault in layman's terms.

Comment: @JasonC Right you are. I modified the answer to reflect your point.

Comment: This is the first answer to actually try to answer OP's question and it should be much higher. +1

Answer (score 14):

Oh, you completed the circuit ***all too well!***  You created an express path for energy from the power plant, through the transformers, to the "hot", through the wire-nut and to the "neutral", back to the transformers and power plant.  Within your home, you made a huge current path, and **lots** of current took advantage of it.  *Too much*, said the breaker!

The trouble is, this very-well-completed circuit wasn't doing anything useful for you, and was making a lot of heat in places you *really* do not want heat.

We want loads to use, but also impede, current flow somewhat.   That can be tricky.  For instance, a fluorescent tube or sodium-vapor lamp is a lot like that wire-nut.  It wants to flow lots and lots of current, so much that the current would destroy the lamp.  That's why they have "ballasts" to impede the current flow just right, so the lamp runs within spec.

Think of hot and neutral as having potential (voltage pressure) between them.  You want it that way.  Any useful load put across them completes the circuit, drawing only as much current as the load requires.

Comment: The circuit does not go back to the power plant. It goes around the secondary of the nearest transformer. Don't post misinformation about electricity.

Comment: @EJP Yes, but that is inductively coupled to the other half of the transformer and from there via the distribution lines to _their_ transformer, and so on. You can model a transformer as a pair of unconnected wires (and a capacitor as a gap), but the conclusions such a model leads to are misleading for AC circuits.

Comment: @EJP I wasn't specific as to what was going through the transformers.   However I can see where you could infer "circuit" from the previous sentence and "current" from the following sentence, which would be wrong and meh, respectively.

Comment: @user207421 not "physically connected" but non the less still connected. What do you think the magnetic flux is doing? E.g., 1 weber/henry = 1 ampere

Answer (score 9):

You say you are new to home wiring and ask a question showing a complete lack of understanding how electricity and home wiring works because a circuit breaker intervened in order to save your life and property.

The point is that a circuit breaker still relies on a number of assumptions regarding the kind of correctness of wiring in order to do its job.  So do a number of other safety measures.

If you continue on your path to learning about home wiring in the manner you do now, you may be less lucky and kill yourself and/or burn down the house and/or kill rescuers or visitors, or yourself or of future tenants who rely on properly done wiring.  Home wiring carries *lots* of potentially lethal and destructive energy, and it's only by properly wiring stuff up that the numerous safeguards built into the system are set up in a manner where they do their job.

Home wiring is a topic utterly unsuitable for learning by trial and error.  It is also utterly unsuitable to approach by a process of assumption and deduction because you cannot afford mistakes, and even if you end up with a configuration that happens to work, any future changes done by someone else on the assumption that stuff is done in a *standard* manner may kill people.

Home wiring is simple and kept simple: there are rules and procedures and standards.  Exactly because the consequences of errors can be terrible.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain this to you in a very simple way,

You said the circuit needs to be completed right ? but for a circuit to be completed you need to have a voltage source , a resistance and some wires to connect them. and when you do so , the circuit completes and the current resistance and voltage are related by the following equation: V=IR

Since you removed the resistance (which in your case was a vent hood) , now the circuit can not be completed. Connecting the hot and neutral wire is equivalent to shorting the voltage source which will cause a huge current to flow through the wires. 
It is the same as connecting the two terminals of the battery when not using , do you always keep the two terminals of an unused battery connected in order to complete the circuit ? NO! 
you just keep it open , but in case of house wiring you terminate it so that it may not accidentally get shorted.

Hope this answers your question.

Remember its always good to make mistakes but in controlled environment, SAFETY FIRST!

Answer (score 0):

> Why did the breaker work when those two wires weren't connected, but when I secures them with a wire nut then all of the lights also on that breaker didn't work?

To put an emphasis on the name of the component:

The breaker working means that the breaker breaks the circuit. If you connect the two wires, you essentially unbreak the circuit, which causes the breaker to break the circuit you've just unbroken.

The job of the breaker is to keep the circuit broken. It might become unbroken (aka connected) by accident or failure. This is why you *don't connect unused hot and neutral wires to “complete the circuit”*, because you actually have installed a device that has the single job that the circuit is never completed (in the way you were completing it).

Comment: The job of a circuit breaker is not to keep the circuit broken (the cheapest way to "keep a circuit broken" would be to remove the breaker entirely and just have no electricity). The high level job of a circuit breaker is to break a circuit *if and only if* the current is too high.